# Display a div after 10s using css animation

Tags: html, css, animation

I am trying to make a birthday card using HTML and CSS. Following is the sample of the code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>

  <title>Happy Birthday !</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.happybirthdaycake2015.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Birthday-Cake-Candles.jpeg" />
  <style>
    html {
      -webkit-animation: chngepic 5s;
      /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
      animation: chngepic 5s;
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes chngepic {
      0% {
        background: url(https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRLZJu3R2KoQA9W4EpcTA3oenwpl9MiWd7AcLX1_V6reXxWVQB7);
      }
      50% {
        background: url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSIZiSe34UlhOVSqfjwNwYZ8gcJfJYzWghkAmnNT1NaT1kca-aW);
      }
      100% {
        background: url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSHz_hTYFVeIKvjZtmj55gXwPoWqK_c-RvILhrQGRu9kJ4c-pO9);
      }
    }
    @keyframes chngepic {
      0% {
        background: url(https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRLZJu3R2KoQA9W4EpcTA3oenwpl9MiWd7AcLX1_V6reXxWVQB7);
      }
      50% {
        background: url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSIZiSe34UlhOVSqfjwNwYZ8gcJfJYzWghkAmnNT1NaT1kca-aW);
      }
      100% {
        background: url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSHz_hTYFVeIKvjZtmj55gXwPoWqK_c-RvILhrQGRu9kJ4c-pO9);
      }
    }
    div.one {
      -webkit-animation: show 5s;
      /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
      -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
      /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
      animation: show 5s;
      animation-delay: 5s;
    }
    div.two {
      -webkit-animation: show 5s;
      /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
      -webkit-animation-delay: 10s;
      /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
      animation: show 5s;
      animation-delay: 10s;
    }
    div.three {
      -webkit-animation: show 5s;
      /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
      -webkit-animation-delay: 15s;
      /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
      animation: show 5s;
      animation-delay: 15s;
    }
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    @-webkit-keyframes show {
      from {
        display: block;
      }
      to {
        display: none;
      }
    }
    @keyframes show {
      from {
        display: block;
      }
      to {
        display: none;
      }
    }
  }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <center>
    <div class="one" style="display: none;">
      <h1>Happy Birthday</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="two" style="display: none;">
      <p>Another year has passed,</p>
      <p>It's your birthday once more,</p>
      <p>You should feel very special,</p>
      <p>And let your spirit soar.</p>

      <p>Celebrate every moment,</p>
      <p>There's no time to be blue,</p>
      <p>Today is your birthday,</p>
      <p>Today is all about you.

        <p>May you always find joy,</p>
        <p>North, south, east and west,</p>
        <p>Happy, happy birthday to you,</p>
        <p>I wish you the very best.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="three" style="display: none;">
      <h2>Happy Birthday Dear!!</h2>
    </div>
  </center>
</body>

</html>
```

What i want to do is after displaying a couple of images i want to show the content in div one after the other. First div with class 1 then 2 and then 3.
I have the above code but does not work properly. After diplaying the images in stops.I want to use only css and no js or jquery

Comment: You cannot animate the **display** property. You would have to use opacity instead.

Comment: I believe you will need JavaScript or jQuery to accomplish what you're looking for.  There is a callback event at the end of the animation, so you need to add an event listener.

Comment: Also, class names cannot start with a number.

Comment: okk I am trying with opacity.

Comment: i found out another property visibility that can be animated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, you cannot animate the `display` property so I would suggest using `opacity` instead.

Additionally, class names cannot start with a number.

Finally, to end the animation and **keep** the final property you must use `animation-fill-mode`. In this case the value would be `forwards`.

```css
html {
    -webkit-animation: chngepic 5s;
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: chngepic 5s;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

}
@-webkit-keyframes chngepic {
    0% {
        background: url(https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRLZJu3R2KoQA9W4EpcTA3oenwpl9MiWd7AcLX1_V6reXxWVQB7);
    }
    50% {
        background: url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSIZiSe34UlhOVSqfjwNwYZ8gcJfJYzWghkAmnNT1NaT1kca-aW);
    }
    100% {
        background: url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSHz_hTYFVeIKvjZtmj55gXwPoWqK_c-RvILhrQGRu9kJ4c-pO9);
    }
}
@keyframes chngepic {
    0% {
        background: url(https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRLZJu3R2KoQA9W4EpcTA3oenwpl9MiWd7AcLX1_V6reXxWVQB7);
    }
    50% {
        background: url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSIZiSe34UlhOVSqfjwNwYZ8gcJfJYzWghkAmnNT1NaT1kca-aW);
    }
    100% {
        background: url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSHz_hTYFVeIKvjZtmj55gXwPoWqK_c-RvILhrQGRu9kJ4c-pO9);
    }
}
.a,
.b,
.c {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: show 5s;
  animation: show 5s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.a {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
  animation-delay: 5s;
}
.b {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 10s;
  animation-delay: 10s;
}
.c {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 15s;
  animation-delay: 15s;
}
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */

@-webkit-keyframes show {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes show {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <h1>Happy Birthday</h1>

</div>
<div class="b">
  <p>Another year has passed,</p>
  <p>It's your birthday once more,</p>
  <p>You should feel very special,</p>
  <p>And let your spirit soar.</p>
  <p>Celebrate every moment,</p>
  <p>There's no time to be blue,</p>
  <p>Today is your birthday,</p>
  <p>Today is all about you.</p>
  <p>May you always find joy,</p>
  <p>North, south, east and west,</p>
  <p>Happy, happy birthday to you,</p>
  <p>I wish you the very best.</p>
</div>
<div class="c">
  <h2>Happy Birthday Dear!!</h2>

</div>
```

Useful article on fill-mode @ [**Sitepoint.com**](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-css-animation-fill-mode-property/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example to fiddle with

### http://jsfiddle.net/albertmatyi/3Lqu0fcL

HTML

```
<div class="one">1</div>
<div class="two">2</div>
<div class="three">3</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    animation: show;
    -webkit-animation: show;
    animation-fill-mode: forward;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forward;
}

.one {
    animation-delay: 0s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
}
.two {
    animation-delay: 5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
}
.three {
    animation-delay: 10s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 10s;
}

@keyframes show {
   from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes show {
   from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for visibility animation use `opacity` instead of `display`